# Math Operations on DateField Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When someone makes an entry, the date and time will be recorded as expected.  What I'm curious about is how to do math operations on that date.  Like I want to show the date of when the object was created, and also the date 2 weeks in the future.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Checkout(models.Model):
    member_id = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    date_checkout = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    # expected_return = date_checkout * 2
```

I thought I had stumbled across a useful resource online that mentioned something about this but I can't find it anymore.  If you could just point me to some resources online that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide a callable as a default and then store that result (assuming you actually want to store the expected_return (ie for queries) )

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
    member_id = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    date_checkout = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    expected_return = models.DateField(default=lambda:datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=14))

Checkout.objects.filter(expeded_return__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
checked_out_item.expected_return
```

if you want it to be an actual field (ie it can be queried `Checkout.objects.filter(expeded_return__lt=datetime.datetime.now())`

if you just want an easy way to access then properties on the class can make functions look like attributes

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
    member_id = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    date_checkout = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    @property
    def expected_return(self):
        return self.date_checkout + datetime.timedelta(days=14)

print(checked_out.expected_return)
```

if you go with the second option you will need to make sure you only use it AFTER the checkout date is set

```
from demo_app.models import Checkout
c = Checkout(member_id=1,title="asd")
c.expected_return # since there is no date_checkout we get error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-4687ba4c4a16>", line 1, in <module>
    c.expected_return # since there is no date_checkout we get error
  File "D:\demo_django\demo_app\models.py", line 11, in expected_return
    return self.date_checkout + datetime.timedelta(days=14)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'
c.save()
c.expected_return # since there is now a checkout it works
Out[6]: datetime.date(2019, 12, 14)

import datetime
c = Checkout(member_id=1,title="asd",date_checkout=datetime.datetime.now())
c.expected_return # since we set the date_checkout it will work even though its not saved
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 14, 13, 36, 21, 270897)
```

Comment: Strange but at first, this worked perfectly.  But when I went to add a new row to the Checkout table, I got a new error.

TypeError at /report/
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'

The strange part is that it says the error is in line 12 of base.html.

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'front_page/main.css' %}">

Otherwise, your suggestion worked perfectly.  I used it to display the date expected for the item to be returned in two weeks.  Thank you

Comment: Exception Value: 
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: you must have used the second option? you need to save your model before you can use the property (or atleast have date_checkout set)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  If it'll make things easier, I can start another question, so I can properly show what's going on.  But Since the last answer I've been getting a different error.  "invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'19 21:09:31.264966'".  It seems any page that calls for information from the Checkout table is getting this error.  And of course, thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Oh and yes I did go with the second option.  I didn't think Django sterilize lambdas.

Comment: thats not really enough of a traceback ... and almost certainly unrelated to this functionality